# Checking if there were no arguments on commandline

Tags: java

While I was going through some tutorial one of the source code file had following to check if there were no command-line arguments :

```
if (null==args[0]) {
  System.err.println("Properties file not specified at command line");
  return;
}
```

Which for obvious reasons throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and doesn't print the message.

So,how to do this check and print the message without getting the exception being thrown?

Answer (score 7):

```
if (args.length == 0) {
  System.err.println("Properties file not specified at command line");
  return;
}
```

When there are no arguments on the command-line, the argument array will be empty. So, you check for its length `args.length==0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (args.length == 0)
```

Just check the length.